# "Variability of" vs "variability in"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

How to choose between "variability of something" and "variability in something"?

Both forms appear to be widely used, e. g. Google: ["variability of this"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22variability%20of%20this%22) (21m results) and ["variability in this"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22variability%20in%20this%22) (27m results). However, in some more specific cases, one form is used exclusively, e. g. ["variability of this factor"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22variability%20of%20this%20factor%22) (500k results) and ["variability in this factor"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22variability%20in%20this%20factor%22) (2 results). On the other hand, the phrases "variability of the data" and "variability in the data" are used with comparable frequencies.

Comment: In the fields of statistics and data analysis, the term used in such contexts isn't "variability" but "variance," so your research should start by using the term "variance" rather than "variability" as any hits you got that use "variability" are going to refer to contexts that don't refer to data or do but are written by laypeople, people who lack sufficient expertise to use the proper terminology. Also, for more grammatically reliable results, results just from published works rather than the whole Internet horde, use Google Ngram (https://books.google.com/ngrams), not a simple Google search.

Answer (score 0):

**How to choose between "variability of something" and "variability in something"?**

Both In and Of are prepositions therefore depending on the noun following "variability **in or of** may be used.

> **variability of** this factor"

In this case **of** is the **preposition for a number** and factor is another name for number.

> **factor** noun (NUMBER)  **of** preposition (AMOUNT) used after words or phrases expressing amount, number, or a particular unit:

In this example

> Both sides agree there is year-to-year **variability in** hurricane activity.

what is actual meant, is there is variability involved with the activity of Hurricanes 
 Both sides agree there is year-to-year **variability INVOLVED with** hurricane activity.

In this case in is the preposition to indicate involvement.

> in preposition (INVOLVED)

also variability can be used without in or of

> The cross-co variance revealed several features of the variability that reinforced other observations

[Link C.E.D](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/variability)
Both sides agree there is year-to-year variability in hurricane activity.

Answer (score 0):

I have found in [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=variability%20of%20%2A%2Cvariability%20in%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cvariability%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20rainfall%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20soil%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20response%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20temperature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cvariability%20in%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20response%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20both%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20performance%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cvariability%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20rainfall%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20soil%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20response%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20of%20temperature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cvariability%20in%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20response%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20both%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvariability%20in%20performance%3B%2Cc0) that you can say ***variability of response*** and ***variability in response*** (the latter is clearly more commonly used).

Both ***variability in temperature*** and ***variability of temperature*** exist as again [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=variability%20of%20temperature%2Cvariability%20in%20temperature&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvariability%20of%20temperature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvariability%20in%20temperature%3B%2Cc0) shows, with not much difference in frequency.

Therefore, I doubt that it is the noun following the structure

> VARIABILITY + ON/IN + NOUN

that determines the use of ***in*** or ***of***.

Note that "variability in" is preferably used with a singular noun (a common feature like shape, age, or an abstract noun like activity, productivity). Here  the stress falls on the noun phrase (in length) showing 'which kind of variability the speaker refers to'. See for example:

> The tongue presents little ***variability in length***, being short and compressed, with a blunt tip, which is never protruded beyond the incisors.

"Variability of" can be followed by a noun in both singular and plural and shows that ***variability*** is *a characteristic possessed by the noun that follows*. See for example:

> A transformation which is sometimes rapid, sometimes slow, but always continuous, is wrought by the reciprocal action of the innate ***variability of plants*** and of the ***variability of the external factors***.

(both examples are from [yourdictionary.com](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/variabilityhttps://sentence.yourdictionary.com/variability)).